# ElasticSearch aggregations get uniques arrays of integers

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I used ElasticSearch for many aggregations types and I encountered a basic problem :

I have integer's array in a field called 'tags'. There are samples of my documents :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "tags":[ 1, 2, 3 ]
},{
    "id": 2,
    "tags":[ 2, 3 ]
},{
    "id": 3,
    "tags":[ 3 ]
},{
    "id": 4,
    "tags":[ 2, 3 ]
}
```

I need to have an aggregation of all uniques arrays as follow :

```
[
    {
        "key" : [ 1, 2, 3 ],
        "doc_count" : 1
    },
    {
        "key" : [ 2, 3 ],
        "doc_count" : 2
    },
    {
        "key" : [ 3 ],
        "doc_count" : 1
    }
]
```

Is that possible ?

---

Basic terms aggregation give that result which is not what I want :

```
[
    {
        "key" : 1,
        "doc_count" : 1
    },
    {
        "key" : 2,
        "doc_count" : 2
    },
    {
        "key" : 3,
        "doc_count" : 3
    }
]
```

With strings, I know that it is possible by disabling analyser but I found nothing with integers in arrays.

I use ElasticSearch 6.0.0.

Thanks for your attention